# CSS Sticky header while disabling horizontal scroll for mobile

Tags: html, css, header, overflow, sticky

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Page>
      <Header>Header</Header>
      <Nav>Nav</Nav>
      <Content>Content</Content>
      <Footer>Footer</Footer>
    </Page>
  );
}

const Page = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
`;

const Header = styled.div`
  background-color: yellow;
`;

const Nav = styled.div`
  background-color: salmon;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200vh;
`;

const Footer = styled.div`
  background-color: crimson;
`;
```

Hi, I have a page layout as you see in the code. And I want  to the be sticky on top of the page. But the problem is when I add overflow-x hidden to html and body to prevent horizontal scrolling when using mobile, sticky won't work. How can I make both to work properly?

[Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-playground-yej56j?file=/src/App.js:64-665)

Comment: use `width: 100%` ( or 100vw) on `page` container not overflow to prevent horizontal scrolling

Comment: I have tried width: 100% and 100vw, and result was same.